# Regular expression for an alphanumeric word start with alphabet

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a requirement to find and return the first occurrence of the pattern from a string.

**Example**: Please find my model number RT21M6211SR/SS and save it

**Expected output**: RT21M6211SR/SS

**Condition for the pattern to match**

1. Combination of digits and alphabets
2. Character length between 6 to 14
3. May or may not contain special characters like '-' or '/'
4. Starts with always alphabet

What I tried, but it didn't work for 4th condition

```
var str = 'Please find my model number RT21M6211SR/SS and save it';
var reg = /\b(\w|\d)[\d|\w-\/]{6,14}\b/;
var extractedMNO = '';
var mg = str.match(reg) || [""];
console.log('regular match mno', mg[0]);
```

Comment: Is the pattern *required* to contain digits, or is it just that it *may* contain digits, in addition to the other constraints?

Comment: It's a mixture of alphabets and digits

Comment: So the digits are *required*, is that it?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes

Comment: `(\w|\d)` is a very convoluted way to write `\w` because `\w` matches digits by itself. `[\d|\w]` is the same as `[|\w]` and matches ASCII letters, digits, `_` or `|` - as the pipe means a literal pipe inside a character class.

Answer (score 2):

`\w` matches word characters, which includes `_` and digits as well. If you only want to match alphabetical characters, use `[a-z]` to match the first character.

Also, because you want to match lengths of 6-14, after matching the first character, you should repeat the character set with `{5,13}`, so that the repeated characters plus the first character comes out to a length of 6-14 characters.

```js
var str = 'Please find my model number RT21M6211SR/SS and save it';
console.log(str.match(/\b[a-z][a-z0-9\/-]{5,13}/gi)[2]);
```

But since the matched string *must* contain digits (and doesn't just *permit* digits), then you need to make sure a digit exists in the matched substring as well, which you can accomplish by using lookahead for a digit right after matching the alphabetical at the start:

```js
var str = 'Please find my model number RT21M6211SR/SS and save it';
console.log(str.match(/\b[a-z](?=[a-z\/-]{0,12}[0-9])[a-z0-9\/-]{5,13}/gi));
//                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you want to permit other special characters, just add them to the character set(s).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried the first set of code it's working in most of the cases but not working when I enter the pattern alone ie var str = RT21M6211SR/SS' and it's giving undefined @CertainPerformance

Comment: I was checking the first one ie console.log(str.match(/\b[a-z][a-z0-9\/-]{5,13}/gi)[2]);

Comment: The `[2]` was there to check the 3rd match, because it wasn't clear whether numbers were required or not (so there were previous matches)